# WPF ListBox DataContextChanged triggers SelectionChanged

Tags: wpf, listbox, datacontext, selectionchanged

I have a user control containing an expander. The content of the explander is a ListBox bound to an object, and a DataTemplate displays it correctly. The problem is this: the user can select a Listbox item, and the SelectionChanged handler changed the DataContext of the ListBox to the selected object.

Like this:

```
<ListBox 
    Name="RelativesLB" ItemsSource="{Binding Relatives}", 
    ItemsTemplate ="{...}",
    Selectionchanged="Relatives_OnSelectionChanged" />
```

And:

```
Relatives_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, ...EventArgs e)
{
    var who = (sender as ListBox).SelectedItem as Person;
    if (who == null)
        return;

    People.DataContext = who;
```

Here is the problem:

1. The `SelectionChanged` event fires.
2. The `DataContext` is changed, and the `ListBox` repopulates.
3. The `SelectionChanged` event fires with `SelectedItem = null`. Here, my code  does not change the `DataContext`; it just returns.
4. the `SelectionChanged` event fires again with `SelectedItem = <whatever is first>`. Here, my code changes the `DataContext` again to that item *I don't want this bit.* Actually, I want to stop after 2.
5. the `Datacontext` is changed to `<whatever is first>`
6. ...
   and so on, until we get an empty `Person.Relatives`, then we stop.

What I want is the stop after the first `DataContext` change. You select a `person` from the `Relatives` collection, and get the view for that person.

How can I stop the subsequent `SelectionChanged` events firing?

Answer (score 0):

I guess, in your on `Relatives_OnSelectionChanged` you need to set

```
e.Handled = True;
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it, but I don't see it preventing new events firing when the selection is changed.

Comment: Muds, I tried it and it made no difference. I think it is for two reasons.

Comment: ... two reasons. Firstly, nothing else is interesting in the `SelectionChanged` event. I don't see why I should not stop it bubbling, though. Secondly, there is a hew `event` when the `DataContext` changes and the `ListBox`is repopulated. I get an `event` when the that happens, and there is nothing selected (`SelectedItem == null`). Then, the first Item gets selected, if there is one, and `SelectionChanged` fires again (and with my code, the `DataContext` changes to that first Item, and on we go. Until we get to an empty `ListBox`.